# iptables are running on reboot even though firewalld and iptables service are not started. Why?

Tags: centos, rhel, iptables, services, firewalld

i have disabled iptables service and firewalld on reboot and also they weren't started. But still, `iptables -L` output some set of rules. Why?

I can flush the iptables configuration and save it permanently. But I don't understand how it is started when the service is completely disabled in RHEL 7.2

Update 1:

[image]

Comment: First, please do not post screenshots from text. Copy and paste text here and format it accordingly. From the subnet that is referenced, it loos like the default subnet which is used by `libvirtd` to route traffic from VMs. So also disable `libvirtd` and you should be done.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I will try this. Can you please tell me what is libvirtd service for any reference link on it. Sorry for screenshot, I couldn't copy the text.

Comment: Ok, it seems I have innstalled virtualization group through yum. It's not applicable, as the server itself is a VM. ok, I will disable it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable & mask on both services should do the trick:

```
systemctl mask firewalld
systemctl mask iptables
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl disable iptables
```

Keep in mind that a disabled service can be loaded, and will be started if a service that depends on it is started. As such, *mask* and *disable* should be the best way to ensure that a service is not started.

Comment: Hi That didn't work. I have done mask and disable for both the services and rebooted. Still iptables is showing something. I have attached screenshot in the question

Comment: Can you get the output from: systemctl daemon-reload ; systemctl status iptables

Comment: It's the same. Just the warning gets removed in the output. However, when I start and stop the iptables. The iptables are not seen running.

Comment: Nice answer in my opinion! I also had a question regarding iptables which I was wondering if you might know the reasoning behind: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359884/understanding-an-iptables-shell-script